# Guess the number: Dynamic Programming -- Identifying Subproblems

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am working on the following problem and having a hell of a time at the moment.

We are playing the Guessing Game. The game will work as follows:

I pick a number between 1 and n.

1. You guess a number.
2. If you guess the right number, you win the game.
3. If you guess the wrong number, then I will tell you whether the number I picked is higher or lower, and you will continue guessing.
4. Every time you guess a wrong number x, you will pay x dollars. If you run out of money, you lose the game.

Given a particular n, return the minimum amount of money you need to guarantee a win regardless of what number I pick.

So, what do I know? Clearly this is a dynamic programming problem. I have two choices, break things up recursively or go ahead and do things bottom up. Bottom up seems like a better choice to me (though technically the max recursion depth would be 100 as we are guaranteed n<=100). The question then is: What do the sub-problems look like?

Well, I think we could start thinking about subarrays (but possible we need subsequences here) so what is the worst case in each possible sub-division kind of thing? That is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]] -> 21
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] -> 9
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] -> 7
...
```

but I don't think I quite have the idea yet. So, to get succinct since this post is kind of long: How are we breaking this up? What is the sub-problem we are trying to solve here?
Relevant Posts:

[Binary Search Doesn't work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861513/binary-search-doesnt-work-in-this-case)